# Conditional Formatting Rules Applying to Different Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

this seems like something that should be relatively easy but I can't get it to work correctly. I have an excel sheet that measures both a goal and a result. I want the result to change to either green or red based on whether it is meeting the goal or not. I have the conditional formatting setup to achieve that with no issue, however, the issue I am having is when I try to apply it to other cells. I have about 400 other lines that it needs to apply to. I have tried dragging the formatting down or copying and pasting individually to each additional cell, but when it's pasted to another cell, it still refers back to the initial cell instead of the cell it was pasted into as a formula would. Is there any way to make this easier at all or do I have to manually add it for each cell? I've attached some images for reference.

[This image is showing the formatting for the first cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8bLT.png)

[When I copy the formatting to another cell, it just adds the cell into applies to instead of changing the cell value to the next value based on its distance from the previous one, as a formula would.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvpB1.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Are you saying that the formatting is *actually* not working correctly?

Comment: I'm sure it is working as intended and I am just doing something incorrectly. In the first image, you can see the conditional formatting is based on the cell value of cell L8. When I copy and paste the formatting into another cell, L9 for example, I want it to then base the formatting off of L9. Instead, it is referring to L8 still. Not sure if there is a way to have it refer to the new cell every time by copying/pasting or if I will have to manually enter it for each cell?

Comment: Everything seems OK to me, have you tested the formatting on the other rows? Note the conditional formatting rules manager will only show the rule for the first cell and apply it (following absolute and relative ranges) to the whole range

Comment: @josh694512 It isn't because the result is equal to the goal, right? both are <= & >= which creates the opening of a conflict they're equal. Otherwise what you're showing looks like it should work.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I see what you mean now. I was under the impression the cell would change each time but now I see it is still following the relative range. Appreciate the help!